# how to search all history command by using bck-i-search in zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I used zsh and when I run `Ctrl-R` to search history command, I can only get the command executed in this session, but can't search all the history commands.
I know there is a `.bash_history` file in bash to store all the history commands and we can do this search in bash.

Is there any way to do this in zsh?

Comment: Is on-my-zsh can do this?

Comment: @NingLee I'm sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Zsh does not save history to a file by default, that's why when changing session your history is removed.
You will have to put in your `~/.zshrc` file  the following:

```
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=10000
setopt appendhistory
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search the history file:

```sh
  % egrep <regexp> ~/.zsh_history
```

or

```sh
  % less ~/.zsh_history
```

and use / command to search

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `Ctrl-R` you may write the first characters of the command then press `↑` key to scroll up the command lines history that starts with the written first characters up to the first usage

Answer (score 0):

To search through history in all sessions, you'll need to enable several options. The [zshoptions](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions) manual page has a History section that lists relevant options.

`SHARE_HISTORY` is one option which will share history between sessions. With this enabled, you should be able to search (using `Ctrl-R` or `history`) through commands run in this and other sessions.